# Java не может импортировать пакеты

Tags: java, netbeans

почему Java не может импортировать пакеты?[Вот](https://github.com/DevonMcGrath/Java-Checkers) репозиторий откуда я скачал
[image: импорты][image: структура]

Comment: а эти пакеты в файлах определены? Или вы просто файлики по папкам раскидали?

Comment: Ну я в Java вообще не силен, но в начале каждого из этих пакетов написано: package model;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ошибка возникает потому, что вы при импорте проекта в netbeans не указали, что папка `src` является корнем исходных файлов (`source root` в терминологии `netbeans`). Это делается на закладке `Source Packages Folder` при импорте.

Для существующего проекта зайдите в `Project Properties` в категорию `Sources` и там добавьте `src` в список `Source Package Folders`:

[image: добавление папки в source package folders]